# Can't get multitouch(3+ finger) working on eOS

Tags: settings, release-juno, touchpad

For some reason I am having trouble getting my trackpad fully working. It feels fine and works well for the most part, including scrolling and tap to click, but I have issues with doing anything with 3+ fingers. For example, I have known that a 3 finger tap should initiate a middle button click. It just acts exactly the same as a 2 finger click. Same situation with 3+ finger swiping: it just scrolls as if there are only 2 fingers on the trackpad.

I am certain that my trackpad can support more than 2 fingers since it does work fine on Windows. It is registered as "ALPSPS/2 ALPS Glidepoint".

I attempted to see the max touch points it will take via geis-tools but it appears to only show my touch screen.

System is a Dell e7250, was also experiencing(albeit much worse) issues chromium.

I have not found a conf file for the touchpad so I assume I need to generate one? I'm still getting my bearings for Linux so advice is appreciated.

**Edit**: Also wanted to add that I had installed(then removed) and configure both libinput-gestures and fusuma and neither exhibited support either so I think it may be something with the driver being used.

**New edit**: I uninstalled libinput and installed evdev as well as synaptics and things are working better. While it means I can't use Fusuma or Libinput-gestures, it does mean that 3 finger clicking is working again and if I can find a gesture package that is compatible I should be able to configure 3 finger gestures at the very least. I don't know if this should be closed at this point because it is more an issue with libinput than it is with eOS. I don't know why lib doesn't support more than 2 fingers for my pad or if that will ever come.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what worked for me. It all revolves around major support issues with the default libinput driver.

**If you Don't care about advanced gestures and only want default gestures such as middle click:**

```
sudo apt remove xserver-xorg-input-libinput && sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics xserver-xorg-input-evdev
```

**If you want advanced gestures follow the instructions in the github link below as well**

Using synaptics drivers will not allow you to use fusuma or libinput-gestures since those both rely on the libinput driver.

[xSwipe by iberianpig on Github](https://github.com/iberianpig/xSwipe)

Answer (score 0):

Probably this could work

https://askubuntu.com/a/214747/890782

I'm sorry that I can't say much about it but just point out the link

Good Luck

Comment: I'll go ahead and add that to the list of things to try tomorrow, but I will note that the e7250 is Ubuntu install certified as of 14.04 and this thread is back from 2012. The original article also notes that even 2 finger gestures weren't working. But I digress, I will give it a shot and report back.

Comment: looks like it will not work...  i was searching and found this for ubuntu/gnome... http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/04/install-touchpad-indicator-ubuntu-18-04-lts/ | https://launchpad.net/~atareao/+archive/ubuntu/atareao

Comment: Well, I went ahead and added the applet because it seems it'll be useful(switched over to Ubuntu to do more troubleshooting), hasn't changed touchpad behavior in any way though. It seems like there is an issue with the libinput driver as I am getting a kernel bug: touch jump detected error. After that error it appears to detect each of the fingers at their different horizontal locations on the trackpad though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the same touchpad as you, Logitech T650, but here is how I got 3 and 4 finger libinput gestures working for the touchpad AND laptop touchpad, Dell XPS 15 9570.

Run the following commands, per [libinput-gestures instructions](https://github.com/bulletmark/libinput-gestures#installation):

```
# Add yourself to input group
sudo gpasswd -a $USER input

# Install utilities needed by libinput-gestures
sudo apt-get install -y xdotool wmctrl libinput-tools

# Get code and install
git clone http://github.com/bulletmark/libinput-gestures
cd libinput-gestures
sudo ./libinput-gestures-setup install

# Clean up
cd ../
rm -r libinput-gestures
```

To customize the gestures, you should run `cp /etc/libinput-gestures.conf ~/.config/libinput-gestures.conf`. Then open `~/.config/libinput-gestures.conf` in your favorite text editor to customize your gestures.

Last you need to actually start the service and set it to auto run:

```
libinput-gestures-setup start && libinput-gestures-setup autostart
```

At this point, I would recommend restarting your device and then checking to see if it works as expected.

Below are several custom gestures I added to make it more "Mac-Like":

```
# Open close overview with 3 figure swipe
gesture swipe up    3 xdotool key super+a
gesture swipe down  3 xdotool key Escape

# Navigate workspaces, swiping right moves to the left workspace, left to the right 
gesture swipe right 3 _internal ws_down
gesture swipe left  3 _internal ws_up

#Optional, but have to do this so gestures work on touchpad and laptop
device all
```

Comment: The libinput drivers for some reason do not support 3+ finger gestures for my trackpad. Not sure why, but I've read through a lot of complaints about libinput being the default driver through my research. Switching back to Synaptics(even though then I can't use libinput gestures or fusuma) was a huge step in the right direction and I got it all figured out after some digging. Will be posting an answer shortly.